# recursive function in python

Tags: python, function

I have a file

```
A      1  N   MET P   1      27.340  24.430   2.614  
A      2  HT1 MET P   1      26.953  23.623   2.168  
A      3  CB  MET P   1      27.740  24.175   3.494  
A      4  H   MET P   1      28.039  24.841   2.028  
A      5  CA  MET P   1      26.266  25.413   2.842  
A      6  HA  MET P   1      25.880  25.742   1.885  
A      7  C   MET P   1      25.112  24.880   3.649  
A      8  HB1 MET P   1      24.236  25.536   3.434 
...   ... ... ... .  ...     .....    .....   .....
```

As a part of the code I will be getting  the value of second column of the file and taking that value I need to decrease its value till third column string should be one of the elements of the `list=['C','N','O']` and append the values of 6,7,8 column values to the list and loop should break as soon as condition get satisfied (since strings in the third column are recursive)
I have tried out this way :Note: `atom_no` is second column value and rl1-readlines

```
dec=int(atom_no)-1
for i in range(0,1231):
       dec=dec-1
       list_coor1=[]
       line1=rl1[i]
       line1=line1.split()
       if len(list_coor1)==0:
          if line1[1]==str(dec):
             for atom in list:
                  if line1[2]==str(atom):
                     for p in range(6,9):
                        list_coor1.append(line1[p])
                        print list_coor1
```

I could not succeed I do think it is problem with decreasing the value i.e., `dec=dec-1` 
As I am intending to do the same by increasing the value of `atom_no`, I tried to define the recursive function but could not do it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not getting the desired output so just wanna know where did i go wrong in the code and i could not debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to find the last line in the file that has C, N or O in column three, and return the values from columns 7 to 9 on that line.

This is simple if you use the features built in to Python, such as iteration and membership checking. Your code is making it much more complicated than necessary with extra if statements and loops.

```
def findLastMatch(lines, startNum, elements):
    for i in range(startNum-1, -1, -1): # iterate backwards from startNum-1
        values = lines[i].split(); # split up the line into columns
        if values[2] in elements:  # does column 3 matches one of the elements?
            return values[-3:]     # if so, return the last three columns
    return None # if we got here, there was no match
```

If you need to do error checking (because your data file may have bad lines) it may get a little more complicated, but probably not by much. There's just a single loop, so any problem with a given line can be passed over by calling `continue` to go onto the next line. If the elements list isn't formatted properly (containing strings) you can pre-process it either in the calling code, or at the top of this function (with e.g. `elements = [str(e) for e in elements]`).

Comment: Thank you very much for ur reply.As i am newbie  to python programming not much aware of built in features.your statement of "you're trying to find the last line in the file that has C, N or O in column 3" is not i mean there but it is  the very first occuring previous line with desired condition.Anyways thanks alot for ur help.

Comment: What do you mean by "previous" here? Is `atom_no` in your original code supposed the starting point from which you search backwards? I'll give a shot at updating my example code to handle that...

Comment: Thanks once again.yeah atom_no in my code is the starting point to search backwards.